# Can I have Windows OS dedicate one or 2 cores to a specific prog./application?

Tags: cpu, performance, multi-core, multitasking

I can often times find benchmarks that compare performance on certain tasks such as for gaming ( Frames per second). However, I have long wanted to use my multiple cores to quickly switch between apps faster. I do understand the concept that CPUs only understand instructions, not programs.

Please consider these questions as a request for tech knowledge, not advice or recommendations on any HW or SW buying choice, which is off topic on this forum. I've also noticed misunderstandings of what I am asking.  When that happens is it possible to add an addendum to my post.  Now back to my actual questions that are the main focus of this posting.

That being said, theoretically, different windows running different apps should be able to do what I have in mind. One example comes to mind,  virtualization. If I purchase a VPS with 2 cpu's do I have exclusive access to 2 physical cpu's?  This is just an example of why it seems theoretically possible.  I do recognize the issue of shared L2 & L3 cache as well as Ram.

I did discover the concept of CPU affinity.  My goal as a software/hw professional is to be more productive when I need to use several applications simultaneously when I work.  When I got my degree in computer engineering in 1989, we applications sending interrupts requiring the computer state to be saved in RAM and then changing tasks/programs and then loading original app and resuming.

What would be desirable is to open Photoshop in one window and then when I move to my coding IDE, Photoshop continues to run on core 1, not affected by another application.  To some degree this might be difficult to achieve as there always 10's or 100's of background apps ( daemon apps on Linux) on computers with CPU'S having 8 cores for example.

With that in mind, it would be desirable to somehow give an app exclusive access to at least one core so that background apps do not cause the Photoshop window to display "not responding".  I did find one software app that addresses application affinity and it uses AI/Machine Learning to improve.  I haven't yet explored manual control of this, where are could designate that one window should have exclusive control of a CPU core and no other thread could interrupt it.

Relatedly, there is an issue I don't know how to address.  Google Chrome opens a new process on Windows OS ( other os's too I imagine).  And switching tabs I see many times on the most latest Cpu's.  Is there any way to address this?

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: While CPU contention can be a problem it is likely not the cause of any "not responging" problems and so locking a program on to a given core is no going to improve anything. More likely your system is starved of RAM and the OS is paging programs out to disk and the "not responding"  is happening while the program is being pulled back in. This is NOT a CPU problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control CPU cores like that. Modern CPU's together with the operating system use [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading). You can set up, start and stop threads and it's then left up the operating system.

I suppose you could create your own operating system from the [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)

Comment: Looks like from the comment above, the solution is extra RAM.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that some applications put out by my Motherboard and that I found online attempt to address this issue.  Interestingly, there seems to be no way to measure effectiveness.  Most benchmarks measure the capabilities of a CPU when running a single application.  None seem to give an overall score for general overall multi-tasking.  Plus, I recognize RAM to be an issue.